# Codeigniter - Limit checkboxes to 9 options, disable the rest and post to a new page?

Tags: codeigniter, post, checkbox, limit

I am looking for a solution, Codeigniter based, to where I can load a page from a MySQL table with check-boxes containing endorsements for the back of an ID card.  I am already able to load the page with a 5 columns by 10 rows of check-boxes which works fine.

What I am not able to do is limit the selection to 9 out of 50 and post the check-box values to another page.

If I use jquery to disable the rest of the unchecked boxes by using this statement:

"$inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true);"

It will only posts the last option that was chosen.  On the other hand, if I don't disable the check-boxes or submit before the limit then the post works fine with an array on the following page containing the endorsements I had chose.  I have been trying many ways to accomplish this in Codeigniter and searching for a solution but to no avail.  If anyone can help me with this, it will be very appreciated.  I am getting close to completing this project and have been struggling with this for a while.

Below is the script that I was using that I had found online:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
var $inputs = $('input:checkbox')
if($(":checkbox").filter(':checked').length==9){
$inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true); 
}else{
$inputs.prop('disabled',false);
}
})
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like when any check box is checked add the class checked and when limit reaches the 9 then disable all checkboxes then remove the disabled attribute from the checkboxes which has the class checked

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
$(this).addClass("checked");
var $inputs = $('input:checkbox')
if($(":checkbox").filter(':checked').length==9){
$("input[type=checkbox]").prop('disabled',true); 
$(".checked").removeAttr("disabled");

// submit the form 
}else{
$inputs.prop('disabled',false);
}
})
})
</script>
```

Comment: dianuj,  Thank you for your reply.  I did try the code you had replied and I am getting a 'ReferenceError:  input is not defined'.  It shows up when I go to hit the 10th endorsement.  Any idea's?

Comment: dianuj, I was able to find what was wrong, I had to the the line:

$(input[type=checkbox]).prop('disabled',true);

to

$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled',true);

Again, thank you for the solution.  I do appreciate it. :)

Comment: @ChrisFallon sorry i was in hurry and didn't realize that i missed the quotes :)